# Has any one connected android client to vert.x server via web socket?

Tags: java, android, websocket, vert.x

Im building a messenger app and need to use websocket to connect my android client to the vert.x server.I cannot find an appropriete client in android to use... i tried okhttp which connected to some test webservers online perfectly and did not connect to my vert.x server... on the other hand ive tried using some easy to use online websocket clients that connected to my vert.x server without any problem..But no connection between two components that i have built

Comment: When u try `okhttp` to connect with vertx sockets, what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to Android blocking non-encrypted connections.

Look up "usesCleartextTraffic" manifest attribute